# "Потом мастерство до одиннадцати вечера" - понятно ли, что речь об уроках актёрского мастерства?

Tags: пунктуация, терминология

> Да, мы раньше гуляли всю ночь, а в девять утра были на акробатике. В
>   час – у станка классического танца, потом мастерство до одиннадцати
>   вечера – и снова вся ночь наша.

Два тире как смотрятся? Оба я нарисовала...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если в кавычки взять "мастерство"?

Здесь же в условном значении - "уроки мастерства", чтобы не смешалось с самим мастерством.

Два тире для меня - нормально, каждое же по своим основаниям, это чувствуется сразу, структура понятна.